# Office 2013 Web Apps Error

Tags: office-web-apps

I've installed the Office 2013 Web Apps in my server. 
The first created Web Application is using office web apps correctly, but when I create a second Web Application and try to open this, following error occurs :

> "Sorry, there was a problem and we can't open this PDF"

It also happenes with other files.

office web apps service is activated in second web application too
,no SSL ,I checked hosts file, recycled app pool, update both servers to last available versions
,http is set ,allowoverhttp is true

I've tried everything I found, but can't solve the problem.

This is the SharePoint server log :

> 03/31/1395 11:00:54.64    w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x5CE8  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request
>   link e0ea879d-23bb-f0d4-2bbf-d951f8d01097
>   03/31/1395 11:00:54.65    w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x5CE8  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Micro Trace uls4    Medium  Micro Trace Tags: 0
>   nasq  e0ea879d-23bb-f0d4-2bbf-d951f8d01097 03/31/1395
>   11:00:54.65   w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x5CE8  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request
>   link).
>   Execution Time=10/9422426593324   e0ea879d-23bb-f0d4-2bbf-d951f8d01097
>   03/31/1395 11:00:54.65    w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope (Request
>   link).
>   Parent No  03/31/1395 11:00:54.67 w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Logging Correlation Data    xmnv    Medium  Name=Request
>   link e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d
>   03/31/1395 11:00:54.67    w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium  Non-OAuth
>   request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|domain\fallah_l,
>   ClaimsCount=27    e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d 03/31/1395
>   11:00:54.68   w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint Foundation   Logging
>   Correlation
>   Data  xmnv    Medium  Site=/  e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d
>   03/31/1395 11:00:54.68    w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization aib35   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.Initialize : Not a
>   ShareByLink request - missing access
>   token e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d 03/31/1395
>   11:00:54.70   w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Authentication
>   Authorization aib35   Medium  SPShareByLinkHandler.Initialize : Not a
>   ShareByLink request - missing access
>   token e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d 03/31/1395
>   11:00:54.72   w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint Foundation   Claims
>   Authentication    amcbl   Medium  Trusted provider is missing. Provider:
>   '00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'    e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d
>   03/31/1395 11:00:54.72    w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Topology    e5mc    Medium  WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress:
>   'net.pipe://localhost/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc'
>   Channel:
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityServices.IApplicationSecurityTokenServiceContract'
>   Action:
>   [link]'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2011/05/securitytokenservice/IApplicationSecurityTokenServiceContract/Issue'
>   MessageId:
>   'urn:uuid:97334139-f41f-430d-8250-3ffdd11f6cf8'   e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d
>   03/31/1395 11:00:54.73    w3wp.exe (0x1A3C)   0x1860  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  nasq    Medium  Entering monitored scope
>   (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Parent No     03/31/1395
>   11:00:54.73   w3wp.exe (0x1A3C)   0x1860  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Topology    e5mb    Medium  WcfReceiveRequest: LocalAddress:
>   'net.pipe://mlc-spsapp.domain.com/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc'
>   Channel: 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel' Action:
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2011/05/securitytokenservice/IApplicationSecurityTokenServiceContract/Issue'
>   MessageId:
>   'urn:uuid:97334139-f41f-430d-8250-3ffdd11f6cf8'   e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d
>   03/31/1395 11:00:54.75    w3wp.exe (0x1A3C)   0x1860  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Micro Trace uls4    Medium  Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,0
>   e5mb  e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d 03/31/1395
>   11:00:54.75   w3wp.exe (0x1A3C)   0x1860  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (ExecuteWcfServerOperation). Execution
>   Time=15/6691702437042 e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d 03/31/1395
>   11:00:54.75   w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint Foundation   Application
>   Authentication    aiv3e   High    Self-issued token request for
>   'wopi/prima@9618ee6b-7a43-4ccd-9210-e2ac2a793d4f'
>   succeeded.    e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d 03/31/1395
>   11:00:54.78   w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    High    Leaving Monitored Scope
>   (EnsureListItemsData). Execution
>   Time=23/4772156796464 e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d 03/31/1395
>   11:00:54.78   w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint Foundation   Micro
>   Trace uls4    Medium  Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,16 agb9s,4 aib35,25
>   aib35,15 amcbl,1 e5mc,24 aiv3e,24
>   b4ly  e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d 03/31/1395
>   11:00:54.78   w3wp.exe (0x72CC)   0x442C  SharePoint
>   Foundation    Monitoring  b4ly    Medium  Leaving Monitored Scope (Request
>   link).
>   Execution Time=121/721336091598   e0ea879d-23bc-f0d4-2bbf-db32a582283d

ULS log in owa server:

06/20/2016 11:00:54.37 w3wp.exe (0x1AB4) 0x2350 ULS Logging Logging Correlation Data xmnv Medium Name=Task: SessionManager.PerformOngoingRequestDepartures 6b6b4445-498b-0002-852d-bd3bc50a677a 06/20/2016 11:00:54.48 w3wp.exe (0x2104) 0x82C8 Office Web Apps Office Web Apps common ajba4 Medium WAC Server HttpModule: Beginning request at target [/wv/wordviewerframe.aspx?PdfMode=1&ui=en%2DUS&rs=fa%2DIR&WOPISrc=http%3A%2F%2Fprima%2FMethodology%2F%5Fvti%5Fbin%2Fwopi%2Eashx%2Ffiles%2F68b8c7605b024f3d8d1dc4c1d7348e64&sc=http%3A%2F%2Fpmo%2FMethodology%2Fguidelines%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&wdEnableRoaming=1] in session [9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51] 9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51 06/20/2016 11:00:54.48 w3wp.exe (0x2104) 0x82C8 ULS Logging Logging Correlation Data xmnv Medium UserSessionId=9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51 9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51 06/20/2016 11:00:54.49 w3wp.exe (0x2104) 0x82C8 Office Web Apps Performance Reporting al3kg Medium User IP Address [UserIPv4:172.22.0.0] 9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51 06/20/2016 11:00:54.49 w3wp.exe (0x2104) 0x82C8 Office Web Apps WAC Hosting Interaction adhse Medium WOPI CheckFileInfo: Start [url:url] 9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51 06/20/2016 11:00:54.49 w3wp.exe (0x2104) 0x82C8 Office Web Apps WAC Hosting Interaction ag7pm Medium URL generated for WOPI CheckFile Request: url 9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51 06/20/2016 11:00:54.49 w3wp.exe (0x2104) 0x82C8 Office Web Apps WAC Hosting Interaction afk6b Medium WOPI Proof Data: AccessToken Hash '1805673443' [1034 bytes], URL 'url' [1189 bytes], TimeStamp '636020010544977919' [8 bytes] 9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51 06/20/2016 11:00:54.49 w3wp.exe (0x2104) 0x82C8 Office Web Apps WAC Hosting Interaction ai85q Medium WOPI Proof: Using Current private key (to sign) that matches Current public key BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAgAAAEAAQBjFooRrhFes15UGFAeVDtrSo2oGFFxN25lOlmABPxjxIUwUmMNEB1+ur7CvTmrGwdxRDSos2v/IBR95R+SX2OC981naTkJbWnQ8hu6DzCFblOtnpYusUTazTiCzE0vceHWQXK8f9Qtb2ORCbDvOIpPnUmWCB1I5HvnYOygqki3WF4dH+Y02WWEW/Mi4fmecUFZJkl2UCWuVwbz6vm0WwOdWsDe6U5JxyTH7kB8vIK6dSk3Sxx7uUMCvVlGaYarMuOvMRFr+pLCRBW31VTCDCyAl2N2ypc66t8G55w9sVtVBAMpweCArol7O9P75QwyEvDaSdm8+1TlrzLg2j6FCQeq 9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51 06/20/2016 11:00:54.49 w3wp.exe (0x2104) 0x82C8 Office Web Apps WAC Hosting Interaction ai85a Medium WOPI Proof - Successfully signed the data with the Current private key [7 ms] 9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51 06/20/2016 11:00:54.51 w3wp.exe (0x2104) 0x82C8 Office Web Apps WAC Hosting Interaction ai85q Medium WOPI Proof: Using Old private key (to sign) that matches Old public key BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAgAAAEAAQBrf9YQJED6/B5xZDlfSBJghbcpwKIM621vRrjPeXG4YJjQRj4zS2vNE8l++wizCAcPjVjxZ1307l+y6Cd5NBJL1Xa6x8ijKB4EYMV/YIfUkwn0BWptbPcsFaktE5vzZYnfld64BEpGfjeOtZ8dFF9io/o6n9uZL70ASIHuqr7m1BMGFLdJB8qeF8gca7nnR+3hL02uobIM7okyUGQ2cdfx/g2IOfHSdap3wPRu/fFSuQH37zY7LSF70XYXyc0GneRbCzNUUFGN0SnikrC4Qbk0pbWMFrJt/G9cb2zoeO1nBK4rTemAGU5us3PlFoCxvk3X+f3xYdP/xY7tu3vW/Jrs 9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51 06/20/2016 11:00:54.51 w3wp.exe (0x2104) 0x82C8 Office Web Apps WAC Hosting Interaction ai85a Medium WOPI Proof - Successfully signed the data with the Old private key [7 ms] 9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51 06/20/2016 11:00:54.51 w3wp.exe (0x2104) 0x82C8 Office Web Apps WAC Hosting Interaction adhq7 Medium HttpRequestAsync (WOPICheckFile,WACSERVER) Starting [mode: GET, url: url?access_token=REDACTED_1062&access_token_ttl=1466440254736] 9be926a8-d9f3-4a8d-b4d0-e1c5e3f05c51

Comment: Can you provide the appropriate ULS log entries from both the SharePoint and Office Web Apps servers for the time when the issue happened?

Comment: i insert the logs in the q body.tnx

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your newly created WebApplication is using Claims instead of Windows classic. You can check this in CentralAdmin -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications -> Mark your WebApplication and klick on "Authentication Providers". "Membership Provider Name" should say "Claims Based Authentication".

You can correct this via PowerShell with Convert-SPWebApplication. If you want to recreate your WebApplication, you must create it with the "AuthenticationProvider" switch in New-SPWebApplication.

Comment: yes it is "Claims Based Authentication"